# Find the Limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{(n+1) \log (1+\frac{1}{n})}$

Tags: limits

Find the limit

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{(n+1) \log (1+\frac{1}{n})}$$

Comment: Please show some effort on your end. What have you tried so far? What are you confused by? This is not a site for us to do your homework on.

Comment: We're happy to give guidance, just not outright solve your problem. What have you tried so far? Is there some part of the theory you've learned that you're not sure on and maybe we can help elucidate? Or are you just stuck as to how to start?

Comment: Learn how to apply L'Hopital's rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: Hint: $\ln(1+1/n)\sim 1/n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $1/n=h\implies h\to0^+$

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{(n+1) \log\left(1+\frac1n\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac h{(h+1)\ln(1+h)}$$

$$=\dfrac1{\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\ln(1+h)}h}\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{h\to0^+}(1+h)}=?$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{(n+1) \log (1+\frac{1}{n})}=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\log\bigg[ (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}\bigg]}$$

Now, use 
$$\lim_n  (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1} =e$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$ $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$ $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$  Let $\frac{1}{n}=t \implies t\to 0\ as \ n\to \infty$ $$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t}{\left(1+t\right)\log\left(1+t\right)}$$ Now, applying L-hospital's rule for $\frac{0}{0}$ form  $$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{d(t)}{dt}}{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\left(1+t\right)\log\left(1+t\right)\right)}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{\left(1+t\right)\frac{1}{(1+t)}+(1)\log\left(1+t\right)}$$ $$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{1+\log(1+t)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{1+\log(1+0)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{1+0}$$ $$=\frac{1}{1}=\color{blue}{1}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{(n+1)\ln(1+\frac1n)} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)^{-1}}{\ln(1+\frac1n)}$$
Using l'Hopital's rule $\big(\frac00\big)$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{-2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}\big(\frac{n}{n+1}\big)}
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\frac{1}{(n+1)\log\left(1+1/n\right)}=\frac{1}{\log\left(1+1/n)^n(1+1/n)\right)}=\frac{1}{\log(1+1/n)^n+\log(1+1/n)}$$